Is the aboleth's mucus cloud ability supposed to hinder affected PCs? It seems beneficial
Aboleths have an ability called Mucus Cloud with the following description:

Mucus Cloud (Ex)
While underwater, an aboleth exudes a cloud of transparent slime. All creatures adjacent to an aboleth must succeed on a DC 20 Fortitude save each round or lose the ability to breathe air (but gain the ability to breathe water) for 3 hours. Renewed contact with an aboleth’s mucus cloud and failing another save extends the effect for another 3 hours. The save DC is Constitution-based.

Since the ability requires a Fort save, it's presumably intended to be a negative effect. However, it specifically says that the aboleth exudes the cloud "while underwater", so it seems like it can affect someone only when it would prevent them from drowning where they normally would.
Is my understanding wrong, or am I missing something? For example, was this ability brought in from a previous edition where it was a more serious condition?


Is my understanding wrong, or am I missing something?

What you’re missing is that you need to consider the ability in the context of the whole fight, and however long it persists after the fight as well.
Overall:

The effect enables characters to directly confront the aboleth without needing contingencies for breathing underwater. This is the only possible benefit for PCs, but it will only very rarely be a benefit, because any party that is fighting an aboleth should already have contingencies for operating underwater in general (not just breathing), and is likely to lose if they don’t have such contingencies and aren’t significantly over-level for the encounter.
Outside of very specific circumstances (being in a very large body of water and having an impressive swim speed and stealth check, or having a way to counteract it (see below)), failing the save means you can’t effectively run from the fight.
Outside of very specific circumstances (direct progress being possible without leaving the water, or having a way to counteract it (again see below)), failing the save means the party as a whole can’t effectively continue on for approximately 3 hours after the fight. This has all kinds of potentially nasty implications depending on the context surrounding the fight.
While affected by Mucus Cloud, anything that can force you out of the water has a much easier way to incapacitate you. The aboleth itself could in theory attempt this approach if it wants by grappling you with a tentacle and holding you out of the water (or just forcing your head above the surface). Any slaves the aboleth has around could also make such an attempt, though it could be risky for them since they likely have the same limitations. Other creatures you encounter after the fight with the aboleth though may also be able to capitalize on this if they discover it. Depending on the conditions of the fight, even time or the terrain could do this too.
Because of how the ability is worded, it is not a poison, disease, curse, spell effect, magic, or condition. This actually makes it very difficult to get rid of the effect of a failed save, because there are almost no spells or abilities that interact with it at all. There are only a handful of ways to counteract the effect, and essentially all are either expensive or dependent on GM interpretation:

The spell Wish, and exactly equivalent effects, can directly negate or remove the effect of Mucus Cloud.
The spell Air Breathing may be able to counteract the effect of Mucus Cloud, but it requires a specific interpretation of the rules for this to be possible. In short, RAW Air Breathing can only target creatures with the ‘aquatic’ subtype (this is normally how a creature has the ability to breathe underwater), but an argument can be made based on how it works and the limitations of the related spell Water Breathing that the RAI is that it can target anything that breathes water. Your GM has to accept that argument for Air Breathing to be usable for this purpose.
The spell Limited Wish may be able to counteract or remove the effect of Mucus Cloud. This is also dependent on GM interpretation. If Air Breathing works, then Limited Wish trivially works by replicating Air Breathing. If Air Breathing does not work, then Limited Wish may still work if you can come up with an approach that counteracts the effect that your GM accepts.
A Crystal Helm can functionally negate the effect of Mucus Cloud, though only while out of the water (when underwater, it fills with air while worn, while out of the water, it fills with water while worn) and you need to be ready to remove it quickly to avoid drowning/suffocating when the Mucus Cloud effect wears off.
A Necklace of Air Adaptation may be able to counteract the effect of Mucus Cloud, but it runs into a very similar issue to that faced by Air Breathing. RAW, it only works for creatures with the ‘aquatic’ subtype, but it’s much harder to argue for it to work for other creatures because of everything it does.
An Iridescent Spindle Ioun Stone may be able to sidestep the issue completely, provided the GM accepts an argument that ‘Sustains a creature without air.’ really means ‘A creature equipping this Ioun Stone does not need to breathe at all.’. This is functionally how it works in just about every case except for Mucus Cloud and the spell Aboleth’s Lung (which replicates the effects of Mucus Cloud in a slightly more limited form), so it’s possible to get at least some GMs to buy in to that argument.


The effect means that an aboleth can have air-breathing slaves operating with it underwater without much difficulty. This is huge from both a tactical and a strategic perspective for a fight with an aboleth.
Because of how the ability is worded, it rather interestingly overrides the ‘amphibious’ special quality. This means it still impacts creatures like mermaids who would normally be able to breathe underwater.
Because it makes it impossible to breathe air, this ability potentially turns Air Bubble (a dirt-cheap option at low levels to deal with breathing underwater) into a liability against an aboleth, though this depends on how the GM interprets Air Bubble as actually working.

There are likely other implications that I’m not thinking of.
This type of ability, where the implications are mostly to do with the circumstances of the fight and less to do with directly harming the PCs, is what I as a GM tend to refer to as a tactical ability. You start to see stuff like this around CR 5-7, and it becomes increasingly common among intelligent creatures as the CR goes up. Tactical abilities like this often do not directly benefit the creature with them, or harm that creature’s opponents, but can generally be used in some way to benefit the creature that has them given sufficient creativity (and it can be safely assumed that any creature with such an ability that isn’t a newborn knows how to use it effectively).

Aboleths are slave masters
Your typical aboleth enslaves a large group of other creatures to do their bidding. This ability keeps their air breathing slaves alive and also prevents them rebelling:

There they are served by countless slaves culled from every nation, air-breathing and aquatic alike, although the air-breathing slaves are doubly bound by magic and the need to constantly replenish their water-breathing ability via the excretions of their aboleth masters.


You'll be stuck in the water for the full three hours, regardless of how things go. So you potentially can't flee from the Aboleth, and depending on the location you're fighting it could try to use this against you in other ways.
How negative this really is depends a lot on circumstances, like how big is the body of water you're in, how much time pressure you're under, are there other enemies that could try to drag you onto dry land to suffocate you and so on. You're right that on its own, this won't do terribly much to hinder you in a straightforward combat, but a DM could get very creative with it.

It prevents you from running away. And PCs typically don't fight nearly as well underwater.
